# How to link PostgreSQL container and PgAdmin in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have a docker-compose file with postgres and pgadmin services in my Laravel project. The problem is that when I do the database migration, it succeeds, but when I go to pgadmin, I do not see the tables I created there. I guess I, as always, made a mistake while writing docker-compose and I just can't find what I was missing.

```
version: '3'
services:
#PHP Service
app:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
        SERVICE_NAME: app
        SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
        - ./docker/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
        - postgres
#Nginx Service
webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www
        - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
        - postgres
#Redis
redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"
#PostgreSQL        
postgres:
    container_name: postgres_container
    image: postgres
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: postgres
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
        PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
        - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    networks:
        - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
        PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-admin}
    volumes:
        - pgadmin:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
        - "${PGADMIN_PORT:-5050}:80"
    networks:
        - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped        
#RabbitMQ
rabbit:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    hostname: "rabbit"
    environment:
        RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "rabbitmq"
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "rabbitmq"
        RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
    ports:
        - "15672:15672"
        - "5672:5672"
    labels:
        NAME: "rabbitmq"  
#ElasticSearch
elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.3
    ports:
        - "9200:9200"
        - "9300:9300"
    networks:
        - postgres
```

#Docker Networks
networks:
postgres:
driver: bridge
volumes:
postgres:
pgadmin:

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In pgAdmin, when you add a new server, you need to define "host.docker.internal" (when on Windows) as Host ([How to add a new server](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/canvaslms/administration/configure-pgadmin)).

Comment: Since they're both on the same Docker network, using the other service's name as a hostname should work, as described in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).  I wouldn't call back to the host for an ordinary inter-container call.